# Dynamic Data DataAnnotations setting dynamically using t4 template

Tags: asp.net, t4, dynamic-data

Is there any way to set dynamically the dataannotations according to some values in database?

My requirement is like this:

```
Display(Name="DispName")]

public string DName{get;set;}
```

Instead of hardcoding Name="DispName" for Display DataAnnotation, I want to fetch some value from DataBase and fit int the Name attribute. like:

```
[Display(Name=SomeValueFromDB)]

public string DName{get;set;}
```

This should be done using t4 template also.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Regards,

Sujith

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if i get what you mean. To me T4 generation doesnt make much sense in your case but have a look at this Phil Haack approach: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx

In contrast to your request he is modifying data annotations at runtime, using custom ModelMetadataProvider.